# Screensaver/black screen doesn't start on its own

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg, power-management, screensaver

Running 16.04, 5 minute inactivity timeout, sometimes the screensaver (or blank screen, to be accurate) won't start until I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and lock the session. Suggestions?

Running Nvidia 367 drivers, currently switched to my integrated Intel card though. Laptop is a Thinkpad T460P, and I am running TLP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion is to try xscreensaver:

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

On my own system I have had more reliable power saving / powering down / blanking with this application. A screenshot from my own Xenial system to demonstrate the power management options:

[image]

And as a bonus there are some truly amazing screensavers...

Comment: I didn't realize it had such great options in there, and via a GUI too! This works. Also, I found it seems to be something running in Chrome preventing the screen from blanking. As soon as I close Chrome, it works fine.