# Screen fails to turn off when inactive

Tags: 14.04, kernel, multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and just recently upgraded my kernel to `4.4.0-36-generic`. Now, after 10 minutes of inactivity, instead of turning off my screens, there's a strange "flicker", all my windows in my additional monitor get yanked over to my primary monitor and windows get shrunk to a smaller size.

Note that after the 10 minutes the screens aren't supposed to lock, just turn off. You can access this setting under "Brightness & Lock" in system settings.

The complete output of `uname -a` is `4.4.0-36-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 11:49:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Does this answer get around the issue: http://askubuntu.com/a/800211/57576 ?

Comment: Alas, it does not. Same behavior. So the problem is more low level it would appear.

Comment: So, while @andrew.46 's suggestion for enabling xscreensaver power management didn't work, using xscreensaver's standard screen saver with power management turned off _does_ work just fine. Not a solution to my problem, I want to understand what broke in the first place, but it's a workaround for now.